# Value added to array when using $project

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am writing an aggregation pipeline to return a win ratio. When I use $sum the value is output from <s>$facet</s> $project *within an array*. This has me confused. To solve the issue I simply run $sum on the arrays when I calculate the winRatio, which works fine. **How do I use $project without it adding values into an array?**

```
Round.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: query,
    },
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      wins: [
        {
          $match: {
            winner: user,
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { user: '$scores.player', game: '$game' },
            value: { $sum: 1 }, // value *not* within array
          },
        },
      ],
      rounds: [
        {
          $unwind: '$scores',
        },
        {
          $match: {
            'scores.player': user,
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { user: '$scores.player', game: '$game' },
            value: { $sum: 1 }, // value *not* within array
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: '$rounds._id',
      rounds: '$rounds.value', // value within an array
      wins: '$wins.value',  // value within an array
      winRatio: { ... },
    },
  },
]);
```

Schema:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    game: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, required: true },
    scores: [
      {
        player: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
        playerName: { type: String }, // denormalise
        score: { type: Number, required: true },
      },
    ],
    winner: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, required: true },
    datePlayed: { type: Date },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

Comment: can you post a scheme of your data? also $facet output is an array regardless what you do in it.

Comment: Have added schema. I ran the code without $project - the values are not in an array. Using $project appears to insert the values into an array.

Comment: so what exactly is your question? $facet returns an aggregation result and by default that is an array. i'm confused why you say without the project its not.

Comment: ok i think ui understand you now after reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asking why `$sum` 'works' and `$project` dosent.

Lets start off by understand the output of the $facet phase.

```
{ 
    "wins" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user" : [
                    "player1", 
                    "player2"
                ], 
                "game" : 1.0
            }, 
            "value" : 2.0
        }
    ], 
    "rounds" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user" : "player1", 
                "game" : 1.0
            }, 
            "value" : 3.0
        }
    ]
}
```

As we can see each document result is an array, even though you grouped at the end, imagine each result as its own aggregation, that return value is always an array (either empty or not depending on results).

so when you `$project` on `$rounds.value` you're telling mongo to keep the value field for each of the results in the array. in our case its only one but still.

`$sum` on the other hand is an accumulative operator, from the docs:

> With a single expression as its operand, if the expression resolves to an array, $sum traverses into the array to operate on the numerical elements of the array to return a single value.

a quick fix to your 'issue' is just to add `$sum` while projecting:

```
{
    $project: {
      _id: '$rounds._id',
      rounds: {$sum: '$rounds.value'},
      wins: {$sum: '$wins.value'},
      winRatio: { ... },
    },
  },
```